# Objects not saved in CoreData db from second time onwards

Tags: ios, database, core-data

I have functionality which clears all objects in DB and adding it again.
It works as expected for the first time but from second time onwards objects are not being inserted into DB.
The functionality works well in the simulator and also in some devices but in most of the devices above scenario happens. Any lead?

Comment: please share the code that you are using.

Comment: Show some line of code..what you have tried.
don't forget to save core data every time after inserting it into db

Comment: It is specifically happening on iOS 11 only, working fine in 12+